# How to make a script that merges all .txt files into one .csv file into multiple columns in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, txt

I don't know how to merge multiple .txt files with datas into one .csv file each of the .txt file seperated into columns.

This is my code so far,

```
$location = (Get-Location).Path
$files = Get-ChildItem $location -Filter "*.asd.txt"
$data = @()

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $fileData = Get-Content $file.FullName

    foreach ($line in $fileData) {
        $lineData = $line -split "\t"
        $data = $lineData[1]
        Add-Content -Path "$location\output.csv" -Value  $data
    } 

}
```

Each of the file looks like this
[image]

I want to keep the first column "WaveLength" and put the second columns next to each other from all the files in the folder. The header will start with the exac name
"stovikmladyDoupno2 202008050000**1**.asd" or "stovikmladyDoupno2 202008050000**2**.asd" and so on ....

so it should look like this
[image]

I have tried to look for information over two days and still don't know. I have tried to put "," on the end of the file, I though excel will handle with that, but nothing helped.

Here I provide few files as test data
https://mega.nz/folder/zNhTzR4Z#rpc-BQdRfm3wxl87r9XUkw

few lines of data

```
Wavelength  stovikmladyDoupno2 2020080500000.asd
350  6.38961399706465E-02 
351  6.14107911262903E-02 
352  6.04866108251357E-02 
353  5.83485359067184E-02 
354  0.054978792413247 
355  5.27014859356317E-02 
356  5.34849237528764E-02 
357  5.32841277775603E-02 
358  5.23466655229364E-02 
359  5.47595002186027E-02 
360  5.22061034631109E-02 
361  4.90149806042666E-02 
362  4.81633530421385E-02 
363  4.83974076557941E-02 
364  4.65219929658367E-02 
365  0.044800930294557 
366  4.47830287392802E-02 
367  4.46947539436297E-02 
368  0.043756926558447 
369  4.31725380363072E-02 
370  4.36867609723618E-02 
371  4.33227601805265E-02 
372  4.29978664449687E-02 
373  4.23860463187361E-02 
374  4.12183604375401E-02 
375  4.14306521081773E-02 
376  4.11760903772502E-02 
377  4.06421127128478E-02 
378  4.09771489689262E-02 
379  4.10083126746385E-02 
380  4.05161601354181E-02 
381  3.97904564387456E-02
```

Comment: so which `WaveLength` to keep? from the first file?

Comment: Yes, the WaveLength is same for all the files. It starts from 1 to 2500.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and copy paste the contents of an example file instead of the screenshot so we can use as test data? Also are you sure `-split "\t"` works? your files are tab delimited for sure? If so you should treat them as TSV and use ``Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t"``

Comment: I have edited the post. There is over 2500 lines in the doc. So it is uploaded in mega.
https://mega.nz/folder/zNhTzR4Z#rpc-BQdRfm3wxl87r9XUkw

Comment: we dont need the complete file, just a few lines of it (10 or so)

Comment: done, it is edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed a location since I'm not fond of declaring file paths without a literal path. Please adjust path as needed.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem J:\Test\*.txt -Recurse 

$Filecount = 0

$ObjectCollectionArray = @()

#Fist parse and collect each row in an array.. While keeping the datetime information from filename. 

foreach($File in $Files){

$Filecount++
Write-Host $Filecount 

$DateTime = $File.fullname.split(" ").split(".")[1]

$Content = Get-Content $File.FullName

foreach($Row in $Content){

    $Split = $Row.Split("`t")

    if($Split[0] -ne 'Wavelength'){

        $Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Datetime' = $DateTime
            'Number' = $Split[0]
            'Wavelength' = $Split[1]
        }

        $ObjectCollectionArray += $Object
    }
}    
}


#Match by number and create a new object with relation to the number and different datetime. 

$GroupedCollection = @()
$Grouped =  $ObjectCollectionArray | Group-Object number

foreach($GroupedNumber in $Grouped){
    $NumberObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Number' = $GroupedNumber.Name
    }


foreach($Occurance in $GroupedNumber.Group){
        $NumberObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $Occurance.Datetime -NotePropertyValue $Occurance.wavelength
}

$GroupedCollection += $NumberObject

}

$GroupedCollection | Export-Csv -Path J:\Test\result.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is quite a hard task, there are a few ways to do it. This method requires that all files are in memory to process them. You can definitely treat these files as [TSVs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values), so [`` Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.3) is an option so you can deal with objects instead of plain text.

```bash
# using this temp dictionary to create objects for each line of each tsv
$tmp  = [ordered]@{}
# get all files and enumerate
$csvs = Get-ChildItem $location -Filter *.asd.txt | ForEach-Object {
    # get their content as objects
    $content  = $_ | Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t"
    # get their property Name that is not `Wavelength`
    $property = $content[0].PSObject.Properties.Where{ $_.Name -ne 'Wavelength' }.Name

    # output an object holding the total lines of this csv,
    # its content and the property name of interest
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Lines    = $content.Count
        Content  = $content
        Property = $property
    }
}

# use a scriptblock to allow streaming so `Export-Csv` starts exporting as
# output is going through the pipeline
& {
    # for loop used for each line of the Tsv having the highest number of lines
    for($i = 0; $i -lt [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Max([int[]] $csvs.Lines); $i++) {
        # this boolean is used to preserve the "Wavelength" value of the first Tsv
        $isFirstCsv = $true

        foreach($csv in $csvs) {
            # if this is the first object
            if($isFirstCsv) {
                # add the value of "Wavelength"
                $tmp['Wavelength'] = $csv.Content[$i].Wavelength
                # and set the bool to false, since we are only using this once
                $isFirstCsv = $false
            }
            # then add the value of each property of each Tsv to the temp dictionary
            $tmp[$csv.Property] = $csv.Content[$i].($csv.Property)
        }

        # then output this object
        [pscustomobject] $tmp
        # clear the temp dictionary
        $tmp.Clear()
    }
} | Export-Csv path\to\result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Wow, good job! I have an error saying 

" Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Max" and the argument count: "1".
At sloupec.ps1:26 char:17 " 

This is the line for($i = 0; $i -lt [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Max([int[]] $csvs.Lines); $i++)

I have set the absolute Path to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much more efficient approach that treats the files as plain text, this method is much faster and memory efficient however not as reliable. It uses [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-7.0) to read the file contents *line-by-line* and a [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-7.0) to construct each line.

```bash
& {
    # get all files and enumerate
    $readers = Get-ChildItem $location -Filter *.asd.txt | ForEach-Object {
        # create a stream reader for each file
        [System.IO.StreamReader] $_.FullName
    }

    # this StringBuilder is used to construct each line
    $sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
    # while any of the readers has more content
    while($readers.EndOfStream -contains $false) {
        # signals this is our first Tsv
        $isFirstReader = $true
        # enumerate each reader
        foreach($reader in $readers) {
            # if this is the first Tsv
            if($isFirstReader) {
                # append the line as-is, only trimming exces white space
                $sb = $sb.Append($reader.ReadLine().Trim())
                $isFirstReader = $false
                # go to next reader
                continue
            }
            # if this is not the first Tsv,
            # split on Tab and exclude the first token (Wavelength)
            $null, $line = $reader.ReadLine().Trim() -split '\t'
            # append a Tab + this line
            $sb = $sb.Append("`t$line")
        }
        # append a new line and output the constructed string
        $sb.AppendLine().ToString()
        # and clear it for next lines
        $sb = $sb.Clear()
    }

    # dispose all readers when done
    $readers | ForEach-Object Dispose
} | Set-Content path\to\result.tsv -NoNewline
```